# Django Google Sign in ModuleNotFoundError at /auth/complete/google-oauth2/

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-signin, django-socialauth

I am trying to create login with google in Django login so when I create my 'Login with Google' it goes to google login page but on selecting Google account it shows an error,

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /auth/complete/google-oauth2/
No module named 'social'
```

My project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('auth/', include(('social_django.urls', 'social_django'), namespace='social')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

settings.py

```
import os

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...,
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
    'django',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    #...
    #...
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'trydjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': '# ...',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # Google login
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',  # Google Login
            ],
        },
    },
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # ...
        # ...
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
   # ....
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
 # 'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',  # for Github authentication
 # 'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',  # for Facebook authentication

 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.debug.debug',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'social.pipeline.debug.debug',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]
# Google+ SignIn (google-plus)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]


SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '*************************.....'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '************************'
```

Here's more description of error:

> Django Version:   2.1 
>  Exception Type:  ModuleNotFoundError 
>   Exception Value: No module named 'social' 
>  Exception
>   Location: /home/barmansvaps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/social_core/utils.py
>   in import_module, line 52 
>  Python
>   Executable:   /home/barmansvaps/anaconda3/bin/python3

Comment: Don't point to `social` in the `PIPELINE` setting, use `social_core` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install *python-social-auth* module. Kindly try this code

```
pip install python-social-auth
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/issues/23).

**UPDATE:**
As suggested by omab. Kindly avoid using outdated libraries which are not maintained and use a library which is currently maintained like [social_core](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core)

Comment: Installing an old and deprecated library is not a good solution and I highly discourage that. Check my comment on the same issue https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/issues/23#issuecomment-403637667

Comment: I completely agree to you. I just helped @Barsmansvaps Friends to solve his problem rather than suggesting him